# bootstrap accordion does not rendering markup correctly

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, salesforce, visualforce

I have the following code,

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <a class="panel-heading visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
    <h4 class="text-danger">
      Urgent
    </h4>
  </a>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">
      some text here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I run the above code the accordion title (a element) does not render correctly.

[image: Code snip-it]

Notice that the `<a>` does not contain any text and instead of placing my `<h4>` inside of the `<a>` it places it outside and creates an entire new element.

I will note that the page the accordion is on is being rerendered, [Salesforce reRender](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm). The page renders correctly and this is the only issue that I am having.

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong or how to fix this? It can be a hacky fix as long as it does fix the markup.

Comment: The accordion markup is modified by js on page load.
If you do a rerender of that section you'll need to re initialize the accordion.

Comment: I googled and looked through the BS guide on accordions but I was unable to actually find how to initialize them. Do I just set them to closed (hidden)? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage